# Help needed with container for a generic item in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates, generics

I wonder if it is possible to define a generic C++ container that stores items as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Item{
typename T value;
}
```

I am aware that the declaration needs the definition of the item type such as:

```
std::vector<Item <int> > items;
```

**Is there any pattern design or wrapper that may solve this issue?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. For one, your `Item` type doesn't store anything. And then, you show a way to do something (`std::vector<Item<int> >`) and then you ask whether this can be done. Why, yes, you can certainly create such a vector. Or what is it that you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 9 types, your best shot is to use `boost::variant`, in comparison to `boost::any` you gain:

- type safety (compile time checks)
- speed (similar to a union, no heap allocation, no `typeid` invocation)

Just use this:

```
typedef boost::variant<Type0, Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4,
                       Type5, Type6, Type7, Type8>        Item;

typedef std::vector<Item> ItemsVector;
```

In order to invoke an operation on `boost::variant`, the best way is to use create a static visitor, read about it in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need a container that can hold elements of any type in it then take a look at [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html).

In your current question there's no big difference between `std::vector<Item <int> >` and `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: The class Item is storing an object of type T. For example, Item<int> should store an integer in the variable "value".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why you can't just use `vector<int>`?

Comment: If the types you want to store in such a container is known at compile time, you can use boost::variant instead of boost::any, which adds some type-safety.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to define a vector<Item> for 9 kinds of Item<T>. Anyway, I think that boost::any can solve my problem.